# Redirecting audio output

Tags: macos, redirect, audio, networking

I need a method to redirect my Mac's audio output to a different computer on the same network as the Mac doesn't have audio output. I'm on Snow Leopard while the other computer which has speakers attached does not have any operating system at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to use Rogue Amoeba's [Nicecast](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/nicecast/). It can hijack system audio and stream it locally so you can pick it up on another machine with any MP3 player that supports streams.

Answer (score 0):

What's the software source of the audio?  If the audio source is iTunes, there are a few things you can do specifically dealing with the support for Airport Express hardware.  If you don't wish to spend more money on Team Apple, then the Enlightenment Sound Daemon runs on pretty much any hardware (Linux, OS/X, or Windows/Cygwin).

There's a quick tutorial [here](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20060602065532384).  It uses Rogue Audio's Hijack; looks like someone's recommended another Rogue Audio project as well.  I'm a fan of Airfoil from them, as it lets me stream Pandora to the Airport Express in the main room.

Comment: Nicecast essentially combines RA's Audio Hijack with an Icecast server; it does it all in one simple package.  And RA are the experts at "hijacking" OS X audio.